# include jspf in another jspf

Tags: jsf, jsp-fragments

I'm working on a JSF project on NetBeans. I'm using JSPF fragments for modularity. My JSPF directory is "/WEB-INF/jspf".  I'm using `<jsp:include page="/WEB-INF/jspf/myincludefile.jspf"/>` for including JSPF files.

The problem is: I tried to include a JSPF file in another JSPF file but it didn't work.

Comment: can you post how did you included the jspf file in your other jspf?

Comment: the same as '<jsp:include page="/WEB-INF/includes/loginform.jspf"/>' i have done this before but it was jsf 1.2. now i'm using jsf 2.1 and it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

Yes I could include JSPF in a nested fashion with the include directive:

```
<%@ include file="/WEB-INF/templates/signin-button.jspf"%>
```

Using JSTL 1.2